# Spview listview item count shows wrong?

Tags: list, list-view, splistitem, discussion-board, spview

We got a list and listview to group our items. But sometimes the total count is showing wrong number. I added sample picture to explain it. In this picture, **Type** is **Form** and it says there is one file in this type. But there are 5 items and it is calculating the count is wrong.

[image]

Comment: is all the 5 items checked in ??

Comment: Yes, there are all checked in. Is there any reason for problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. This could be the problem with the documents checked in problem.

**How does it work?**

Normally what happens, there are documents in the library that were uploaded for the first time and never checked in, so only the owner of the files can see them no matter the view or permissions you have.

You can navigate to the Library settings page and then click on "Manage checked out files" and you will probably see the remaining files of the total number of items that SharePoint is seeing.

Comment: There are all checked in. Is there any reason for problem?